# Передать php переменную через ajax (WordPress)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Я использую ajax для загрузки некоторой информации на страницу, Ajax запрос использует php файл, который никакого отношения к WordPress не имеет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне сделать, чтоб функции, находящиеся в function.php темы, были доступны для этого файла. Пробовал:

```
include('http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/wp-load.php');
```

Не помогло, пробовал

```
require_once('function.php')
```

Или, может быть, можно передать результат выполнения функции через GET?

Answer (score 1):

В вашем файле нужно подключить функционал WordPress, тогда станут доступны функции из functions.php

```
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );
```

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле, я выяснил, что это не самый лучший путь. Загрузка WordPress удваивает нагрузку на сервер, с учетом того что у ресурса над которым я веду работу посещаемость более 2000 человек в день, это критично. В этой статье, я нашел подробное руководство о том как можно решить мою проблему. 
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/

Comment: То, что вы нашли - абсолютно стандартный ajax для WordPress, который проводит инициализацию WordPress. Да, неполную, но все равно - инициализацию ядра.

Comment: чуть офтопну. 2к человек в день - это мелочь, не достойная  внимания, если рассуждать о "нагрузках".