# Как получить в AJAX переменную из php в WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Всем привет, есть задача получить рубрику в переменную, после этого с помощью AJAX получить это переменную для дальнейших манипуляций с ней в Jquery.

```
<?php
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action');
    function my_action(){
    $pharmacies = get_category(22);
    echo json_encode($pharmacies);
    wp_die();
    }
?>
```

Задача в php коде по запросу передать переменную, в AJAX ее получить, помогите реализовать.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Передать php переменную через ajax (WordPress)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481267/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-php-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-ajax-wordpress)

Comment: Почитайте руководство на русском: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html